# How can I configure max length of column name in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, maxlength

The max length of column name in MySQL is 64 (you can check [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html)).
My question is how can I change it.
To be more specific, I want to increase it.
Can it be done? if yes, how it should be done?

Edit: Few words on the motivation:
These tables are created automatically upon strings input, and not needed to be readable, as they are being used by the software.
The alternative is to give some "id" as column name instead of the input string concatenation. However increasing the column name length can solve it without any code change.

Thanks,

Lior

Comment: you have 2 options. Ask MySQL developers to do it or you can download the code and modify according to your requirements.

Comment: 64 characters *really* ought to be enough for most [sane] column name limits. I wouldn't be surprised if the length restriction was fixed in the code-base (including binary schema formats) and not trivially changed, even with source-code access.

Comment: if column name don't matter (i don't know how you are going to read data back) you can use `base64` encoded SHA1 hash to create field name. SHA1 hash is only 160 bits. If you think there is going to be a clash you can even use SHA256 which is only 256 bits. Anyhow you need code editing. If you are going to edit MySQL code it is not that easy and you cannot run your application in any other MySQL installation.

Comment: If you think you absolutely require column name length more than 64. Here is a trick (but **NEVER TRY THIS** in a production server). Just alter the table `information_schema.COLUMNS` and change the `COLUMN_NAME` column from `VARCHAR(64)` to your comfortable size. There is no guarantee this may work. Be careful you may mess up your MySQL installation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can not be done. Why do you want to have a column name exceeding 64 in length?

Comment: This is wrong. It certainly can be done by changing the source code of mysql.

Comment: @bansi In vague theory .. yes. In practice .. maybe (although likely not trivial). It depends upon the actual source-code layout and usage of such data.

Comment: I've added the motivation to the question.

Comment: the question was to _configure_. Rewriting source is not configuration, so this answer is correct.